# Bottom Navigation Bar con Jetpack Compose y Material Design 3 en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jetpack-compose

Estoy trabajando con Kotlin, MVVM, JetPack Compose y Material 3.

Tengo que hacer un login que al presionar el botón (si todo está bien), debe navegar con Navigation a un Bottom Navigation Bar, es decir, de un screen login a otro Screen que tenga el bottom Navigation Bar.

Les comento que si ejecuto la APP y coloco como lanzamiento un archivo que tengo que se llama *BottomNavigationBar()* la app funciona perfecto y levanta con ese Composable mostrándose el Bottom Navigation Bar y funciona perfecto.

Intento hacer lo mismo pero primero que se visualice el Composable Login y luego pasar a esta otra pantalla, da **error** *al momento de presionar el botón de Login.*

El onClick es este:

```
onClick = {
        navController.navigate(Destinations.Jobs.route){
            launchSingleTop = true
        }
    },
```

Pero no estoy seguro de que esto esté bien.

Los 3 Composables que se ven en el Bottom Navigation Bar son Jobs, Options y Settings.

Lo raro es que como mencione si no paso por el Login funciona bien, es decir que el error estaría en intentar navegar desde el Login a este otro Composable.

El error que arroja es el siguiente:

```
Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/BottomNavigationBar }. Navigation graph has not been set for NavController androidx.navigation.NavHostController@913a24b.
```

Como es mucho código y quizás se haga muy extenso el ponerlo todo aquí, les dejo mi [repositorio](https://github.com/maurotello/tareasCampo) para ver si me pueden ayudar con esto.

Aclaro que en el MainActivity.kt el Composable que ejecuto cuando anda es el BottomNavigationBar, como se ve en el código que les dejo.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        TareasCampoTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                LoginScreen(loginViewModel, navController = NavHostController(this))
                //BottomNavigationBar()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece que el mensaje de error es claro: *`Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/BottomNavigationBar }. Navigation graph has not been set for NavController ... `*. No está encontrando el destino **`BottomNavigationBar`** y es que [lo tienes comentado en `Destinations`](https://github.com/maurotello/tareasCampo/blob/6adc28a8e7cd6f2eb6d025334c364f8f0c08daec/app/src/main/java/com/maurotellodev/tareascampo/navigation/ui/Destinations.kt#L14).